# istio sidecar giving 403 RBAC because of AuthorizationPolicy

Tags: istio, kubeflow

I am trying to use Kubeflow serving (kserve) but my model (sidecar) giving 403 RBAC issues. Below is `AuthorizationPolicy` rules

```yaml
rules:
    - from:
        - source:
            principals:
              - >-
                cluster.local/ns/istio-system/sa/istio-ingressgateway-service-account
              - cluster.local/ns/kubeflow/sa/ml-pipeline-ui
      when:
        - key: request.headers[kubeflow-userid]
          values:
            - user@example.com
    - when:
        - key: source.namespace
          values:
            - kubeflow-user-example-com
    - to:
        - operation:
            paths:
              - /healthz
              - /metrics
              - /wait-for-drain
    - from:
        - source:
            principals:
              - cluster.local/ns/kubeflow/sa/notebook-controller-service-account
      to:
        - operation:
            methods:
              - GET
            paths:
              - '*/api/kernels'
```

My request is going through `istio-ingressgateway` & it has the proper cookie. `oidc-authservice` can find a user & it is adding `kubeflow-userid` in the header. But when a request is going to the actual model, the sidecar in that pod gives 403.